# How to loop task input, save previous to-do list to next program run and delete inputs?

Tags: java, arrays

I made a To-Do list, that inputs at the end of the program, tasks that I wrote using Scanner util, and my problem is that after program is executed, it writes all tasks, and I want it to let me save this list of tasks somewhere, and later delete tasks that I made. I guess that y'all know what I'm talking about, but I'm a beginner and don't know how to make it, because i thought of splitting this program to 3 parts:

1. Inserting tasks
2. Saving tasks,
3. Deleting tasks and making other list

but I guess I can do it in one source. Thanks for help!

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner task = new Scanner(System.in);
String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

System.out.println("Put in the task: ");
String task1 = task.nextLine();
System.out.println("Is that all(1-yes/0-no)?  ");
double answer1 = input.nextDouble();
if (answer1 == 1) {
  System.out.println("Your tasks for today are:\n" + task1);
  System.exit(0);
} else if (answer1 == 0) {
  System.out.println("");
}
/* and the sequence is looped */
```

Comment: Can you explain why you are calling system.exit if the sequence loop or code that follows is expected to execute?

Comment: Because, in my code, there is answer 2,3,4 and when there wasnt System.exit, the tasks question would still be asked I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method with a while loop for this:

```
public class Main {

    private static List<String> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       parseTasks(); //fill our list of tasks
       //do something with your tasks here, I print them for example
       System.out.println("Your tasks for today are:");
       tasks.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static void parseTasks() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        boolean moreTasks = true;
        while(moreTasks) { 
            System.out.println("Enter the task:");
            tasks.add(input.nextLine()); //save user input to list
            System.out.println("Is that all(1-yes/0-no)?");
            int userDecision = input.nextInt();
            moreTasks = userDecision == 1 ? true : false; //check if we need more tasks
        }
    } 

}
```